# Is this correct? Relation Algebra DBMS NOT SQL

Tags: relational-algebra, relational

```
INSTITUTION (InstitutionName, State)
PRESENTER (PresenterName, Biography, InstitutionName)
```

My Question is: List the name, biography, and institution of all presenters from an institution in WA.

My Answer is :

```
RESTRICT PresenterName, Biography, InstitutionName (PROJECT State = 'WA'(INSTITUTION));
```

Here is an example from my notes

'Give the name and salary of all employees who work in department 5'

EMPLOYEE (E#, Name, Salary, Dept)

```
RESTRICT Name, Salary (PROJECT Dept = 5(EMPLOYEE))
```

Comment: Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & explain your work. Also you are not calling either operator correctly. Also please see how your question format has been improved by editing.

Comment: re "example from notes": are you _sure_ that's how you were told to use those operators? Usually `PROJECT` corresponds to Projection (π), `RESTRICT` corresponds to Selection (σ). Yes `*` is sometimes used for Natural join (⋈). My answer uses a variant, to get you to think what it means.

Comment: OMG the Lecture notes are wrong.. *facepalm* my bad.. it is indeed PROJECT  for Projection (π) and RESTRICT for Selection (σ).

Answer (score 2):

```
PRESENTER ⋉ (σ{State = 'WA'}(INSTITUTION));
```

I've used the operators per [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra).

(**EDIT** in response to comments: I've put `{ ... }` where wikipedia shows subscripting of components of an operator. Compare the operator names you're using (and your definitions for them) to the definitions in wikipedia.)

As @philipxy points out, your answer is not using operators correctly. Please explain which operator names and syntax your lecturer/textbook wants you to use.

Comment: So the Projection = RESTRICT and Selection = PROJECT. but We've  not used { } ever..

Comment: Natural Join is R1*R2 for us. so RESTRICT pre,bio,inst(PROJECT state = 'wa' (PRESENTER * INSTITUTION)) I'm assuming

Comment: @Mohammed No, pi=project=projection takes attributes & sigma=restrict=restriction=select=selection takes a condition & there is a typo in your notes. Please find the definitions you were given and/or get corrections & edit your post per my comments.